# How to start a new line after each appearance of a specific substring in txt file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this txt file named "Poo.txt": 
"iF   you   happen  to  have  read  another  book  about
Christopher Robin, you may remember that he once had a swan (or
the swan had Christopher Robin, I don't know which) and that he.
used to call this swan Pooh. that was a long time ago, and when
we said good-bye, we took the name with us, as we didn't  think
the  swan  would  want it any more. Well, when Edward Bear said
that he would like an exciting name all to himself, Christopher
Robin said at once, without stopping  to  think,  that  he  was
Winnie-the-Pooh.  And  he was. so, as I have explained the Pooh
part, I will now explain the rest of it"

And I need that after the substring "en" it will start a new line. So the output will be in a new file : "outfileq2.txt" and the text in it will be as shown in the image. [output in the "outfileq2.txt"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA3gK.png)

I have tried something like this:

```
outfname = 'outfileq2.txt'
with open("Poo.txt") as f:

    with open(outfname, "w") as f1:
        f1.writelines()
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading each line you could use regular expressions to change your string.

```
import re

outLine = re.sub("em","em\n"", line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check if the substring is present in the given word or not and then \n every time you get a substring

```
def exactMatch(text, lenText, curr_pos, pat, curr_pos_pat, lenPat):

    if curr_pos == lenText:
        return False
    if curr_pos_pat == lenPat:
        return True
    if text[curr_pos] == pat[curr_pos_pat]:
        return exactMatch(text, lenText, curr_pos + 1, pat, curr_pos_pat + 1,lenPat)
    return False
def contains(text, lenText, curr_pos, pat, curr_pos_pat, lenPat):
    if curr_pos == lenText:
        return False
    if text[curr_pos] == pat[curr_pos_pat]:
        if exactMatch(text, lenText, curr_pos, pat, 0, lenPat):
            return 1
        else:
            return contains(text, lenText, curr_pos + 1, pat, curr_pos_pat, lenPat)
    else:
        return contains(text, lenText, curr_pos + 1, pat, curr_pos_pat, lenPat)
text = input()
pat = input()
lenText = len(text)
lenPat = len(pat)
curr_pos_pat = 0
print(contains(text, lenText, 0, pat, curr_pos_pat, lenPat))
```